# How to drop column using Entity Framework code-first approach with enable migration

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Mistakenly I have created 2 same columns (`MembershipTypeId`, `MembershipType_Id`) in database.

Now I need to drop one of those columns (`Membership_Id`). How can I drop this column, using EF code-first approach with migration in ASP.NET MVC 5?

[Image is attached for more references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkJ43.png)

Comment: In Code First, you can change the code model and use a migration to update the database. Really need to see your model. The MembershipType_Id may have been created by EF if you define a relationship without the proper foreign key configuration.

Comment: Thanks @SteveGreene for answering me.